# Pushing data to a model with the router in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone-routing

Something seems off about this approach... I have inherited a backbone project and this is how the routing was done:

```
APP.routes.on("route:default", function( actions ) {
    var url = some.api
    jsonp.request(url,function(data){
        var model= new mModel(data.someData);            
        var view = new MyView({model:model});
    });
});
```

I am wondering if this is a standard acceptable approach or if not what would be a better solution. I cannot find any example of anyone doing this type of architecture. A complete code refactor is not 100% feasible but I am trying to write up some concerns. My concern is that the model and view here are very tightly coupled. This pattern is repeated for 30 or so routes, all with their own model / view paring. The application is also making nested JSON requests from with the views directly which is a completely separate issue. Anyway, the app is VERY slow and I am trying to narrow out reasons why, like I said, this looks suspect to say the least.

Comment: how to set the data to model? is that the question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How to properly use Backbone's Router is pretty up for debate, but generally you want to present the user with content ASAP, even if it's just a loader because that's better than nothing. The code should probably have been more like:

```
APP.routes.on("route:default", function( actions ) {
    var view = new MyView

    view.render()
});
```

MyView.js

```
// Abstract away the model's logic into the view
var MyView = Backbone.View.extend({

     el: '#main-content',

     template: _.template( '<blah>Some template</blah>' ),

     initialize: function(){
        this.model = new mModel()
     },

     // The model needs data first, so just return a loader while we wait
     render: function(){
        this.model.fetch({ 
            success: _.bind( this.onModelDoneFetching, this )
        })
        this.$el.html('<img class="loader" alt="Loading content" />')
        return this
     },

     // the model has the data so we can render content now
     onModelDoneFetching: function(){
        this.$el.html( this.template( this.model.toJSON() ) )
     }

})
```

If you're noticing the `jsonp` floating around instead of `fetch` ever being used, it's probably because the API for your app isn't on the same domain. In this case, overriding Backbone's internal AJAX method would have been best. Doing so would look something like:

```
Backbone.ajax = jsonp
```

The app's slowness is probably not due to the UI though - most likely the cross-origin requests are where the performance is lagging.

Comment: Thanks. My inclination was to handle the requests like this as well... I will have to see if we can still find out why it was built the way it was. There are a whole bunch of reasons why this is app is slow that I won't get into but yes, cross domain stuff is a factor.

Comment: Yeah but at least you've identified what areas need work. Good luck with everything!